# Json converts & in a String to \u0026

Tags: java, json, string, unicode, gson

I am trying to extract text from pdf and write it into a json file. While extracting unicode characters the Json converts all & to \u0026. For example my actual String is `&#1588`. (which represents ش). It prints correctly to a .txt file, to console etc. But when I try to print this string to a Json file it shows `\u0026#1588;`.

I am using Java, and the code is

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(pdfDoc);
```

Note: `pdfDoc` is an object, that contains all the details (position, color, font.. etc) of characters inside the input PDF document.  I am using `gson-2.2.1.jar`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's actually a valid (but not required) encoding. *Any* character *may* be encoded using the unicode escape in JSON and any valid JSON parsing library *must* be able to interpret those escapes.

`&` is not part of the characters that *need* encoding (see the definition of `string` [at json.org](http://json.org/)), but there are a few JSON libraries that are quite "aggressive" in their encoding. That's not usually a problem, unless you don't really handle the resulting JSON with a conforming JSON parser.

[GsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) will help you turn that feature off if you absolutely need to.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I changed the code to Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

Comment: One of these "aggressive" libraries is unsplash.com. Using following code to decode it in swift: extension String {
    func utf8DecodedString()-> String {
        let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
        let message = String(data: data!, encoding: .nonLossyASCII) ?? ""
        return message
    }
    
    func utf8EncodedString()-> String {
        let messageData = self.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)
        let text = String(data: messageData!, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        return text
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Using following code to decode \u0026 from a unsplash.com JSON file in Swift:

```
extension String {
    func utf8DecodedString()-> String {
        let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
        let message = String(data: data!, encoding: .nonLossyASCII) ?? ""
        return message
    }
    
    func utf8EncodedString()-> String {
        let messageData = self.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)
        let text = String(data: messageData!, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        return text
    }
}

let jsonOriginal = #"Let\u2019s not be na\357ve \u0026 dumb!"#

print(jsonOriginal)
print("----")

let jsonDecoded = jsonOriginal.utf8DecodedString()
print(jsonDecoded)

let jsonEncoded = jsonDecoded.utf8EncodedString()
print(jsonEncoded)
```

Curiously, encoding leaves & and will not recoding to \u0026??