# Syntax error when parsing a valud JSON using jQuery.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've written a small web servlet which returns the [screening schedule of my local cinematheque as JSON text](http://cinema-sderot.appspot.com/getSchedule).

The result is a valid JSON object:

```
wget -qO- "http://cinema-sderot.appspot.com/getSchedule" | python -mjson.tool
```

The next step is AJAX-ing this JSON from a web page using [jQuery's getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). I've [modified a simple W3schools snippet](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://cinema-sderot.appspot.com/getSchedule",function(result){
        $("div").append(result);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code should put the contents of the JSON into the div when the button is pressed. It fails both in Chrome and Firefox with:

> SyntaxError: JSON Parse: unexpected end of data

This is strange, because the JSON is tested to be valid. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: JSLint calls false on that JSON being valid! `Unexpected \`` in `"title": "צעירה ויפה - Young \u0026 Beautiful",` -- Line 1779

Comment: That makes more sense. How did you get that messsage?

Comment: Pasted the response from the site above into JSLint, hit the JSLint button and check the errors at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know JSLint. Is `\u0026` the problem? If so, How can I fix it on the client side?

Comment: The JSON is created using Gson. This is probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702249/json-converts-in-a-string-to-u0026

Comment: Voting to close. This is a manifestation of a strange Gson behaviour, and it was answered in another question.