# Jackson- reading '&amp' into unicode \u0026

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using the jackson-dataformat-xml to read some xml.

In some of the Strings its reading the xml special character `&` as: `&amp;`

When jackson reads it into a POJO the character is turned into: `\u0026`

for e.g. the string Air "`B&amp;B`" is turned into "`Air B\u0026B`".

Is it possible to direct jackson to convert this string to "`Air B&B`" instead of "`Air B\u0026B`"?

Comment: Actually why would it matter? They would both print the same thing

Comment: These strings will be used for further processing. for e.g. the value is then converted into json we dont want the json to have \u0026 in there.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573452/how-to-prevent-objectmapper-from-converting-escaped-unicode) seems related

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702395/14419